# When the data size and processor speed are both multiplied by 10, then a linearithmic algorithm takes double the time to finish?

Tags: asymptotics

Robert Sedgewick mentioned, if a computer can handle 10x data and the processor is also 10x as fast, then a $ O(n^2) $ algorithm actually runs slower than before.

Is this the correct idea when a computer has 10x RAM and can handle 10x data all at once, and also have a processor that is 10x faster, then:

1. A $ O(n^2) $ solution is slower, because now $ n^2 $ is 100 times, but processor is only faster by 10 times. So the time it takes to solve the problem is 10 times more. So if it took 1 hour to solve the problem before, now it would take 10 hours.
2. If it is a $ O(n \log n) $ solution, then roughly speaking, for $ n \log n $, it is

   $ (100 \log 100) / (10 \log 10)   
     = (100 / 10) \times  (\log 100 / \log 10)    
     = 10 \times log_{10} 100 = 20 $

and since the processor is 10 times as fast, that means now the algorithm is "half as fast"? (meaning if it took 1 hour to solve the whole problem before, now it would take 2 hours)

Comment: Try n = 1,000,000 instead of n = 100.

Comment: in terms of calculation, using 100 vs 10, or using 10,000,000 vs 1,000,000 I think is the same

Answer (score 1):

I don't like how you expressed this - the ten times faster computer is ten times faster. It will solve the same problem and answer the same question ten times faster. Of course if you give it a question that would take 100 times longer on the old computer, then it will take only 10 times longer on the new computer.

If you had an algorithm that took n log n microseconds (and in CS "log" usually means log base 2) to solve a problem of size n, a problem of size 10 n would take 10n log (10n) microseconds on the old computer, and n log(10n) microseconds on the new computer.

log (10n) isn't ten times or twice as much as log n - the factor 10 turns into a constant. log (10n) = log n + log 10 ≈ log n + 3.3. If n = 10 it's twice as much. If n = 10 billion it's only ten percent more.

Two things to consider: No computer is just "ten times faster". A computer does many different kinds of operations. Some may be ten times faster, some even more, some less. And Big-O is concerned about asymptotic values: I could have an algorithm that takes on my computer n^2 microseconds if n ≤ 1,000,000 and 10n^2 microseconds if n > 1,000,000. So if you want to find actual execution times, you need more than Big-O.

And it is *very* common that actual execution times are quite different from what Big-O makes you belief when n is small. For example, let f(n) = n + 1000 log n. f(n) = O(n). But for n ≤ 10,000 f doesn't behave very linear at all.

Comment: I think what Robert Sedgewick was saying is something like this: if you are in some research or solving some kind of problem, in the past, you might only dare to have sample data, say 100,000 or 1,000,000, but now with a computer having 10x the RAM and 10x as fast processor (say, from 400MHz to 4GHz), then you dare to increase the sample data to 1,000,000 or even 10,000,000 -- that's what he meant. And then you find that if you have a $ O (n^2) $ solution, it actually takes 10 times the duration to solve it as before